# How to remove Parent of Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am removing button control from one list to another listh and following error occures

"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first"

any idea how to remove that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fairly easy:

1. [Get the list of controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) from your parent control.
2. Call the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.remove%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) function on that list to remove your control.

So something like this:

```
myListControl.Controls.Remove(myControlToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Util.PlaceControlToContainer(this.button1, this.panel2);
        }
}
public static class Util
{
   public static void PlaceControlToContainer(Control control, Control container)
   {
       lock (control)
       {
          if (control.Parent != null)
          {
              control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
          }
          container.Controls.Add(control);
       }
   }
}
```